# psql: FATAL: role "user" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql

My psql does not open. Weirdly enough. I've created a user "Ben" through logging using `psql -U postgres` that lets me open PSQL and I run a command

```
CREATE USER Ben WITH PASSWORD '123';
```

After I do that it says `ERROR:  role "ben" already exists`

But when I run psql it throws me `psql: FATAL:  role "Ben" does not exist`

Comment: Case matters. Either be consistent everywhere and use lowercase or wrap it in double quotes.

Comment: Ahhh, would it resolve if I DROP User Ben; then recreate like CREATE USER Ben WITH PASSWORD '123';

Comment: How `Ben` is different to `Ben` though?

Comment: They're the same thing?

Comment: I don't see the difference between `Ben` and `Ben`.

Comment: I created a user Ben. Still says Ben does not exist. How would I resolve this then?

Comment: No, you created `ben`. If not wrapped in double quotes - it is lowercased.

Comment: Ah, saw your edit. Makes sense!

Comment: postgres=# CREATE USER "Ben" WITH PASSWORD '123' when I run psql says psql: FATAL:  database "Ben" does not exist

Comment: Ok. And you wrote that because... ?

Comment: Why is it throwing me database does not exist. Earlier it was throwing user based error. Now it's database after I created the user with quote "Ben"

Comment: so, database `Ben` does not exist. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

When you issue an SQL command like this:

```
CREATE USER Ben WITH PASSWORD '123';
```

identifiers within this command (such as the user name) are folded to lower case. So the user is actually created as 'ben'.

When you issue a shell command such as:

```
psql -U Ben mydatabase
```

then the identifier case is preserved, making it case sensitive.

If you really want the user name capitalized, then double quote it in SQL, like this:

```
CREATE USER "Ben" WITH PASSWORD '123';
```

Otherwise leave it all lower case and connect with:

```
psql -U ben mydatabase
```

See: [Identifiers & Keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual